# What is `$?` in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

What is the meaning of `$?` in Powershell?

---

Edit: [TechNet answers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.4) in tautology, without explaining what 'succeed' or 'fail' mean.

> $?
> Contains the execution status of the last operation. It contains TRUE if the last command succeeded and FALSE if it failed.

I presumed `$?` would simply test whether `$LastExitCode` is 0, but I found a [counter example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666101/powershell-lastexitcode-0-but-false-redirecting-stderr-to-stdout-gives-nat) where `$?` is False but `$LastExitCode` is True.

Comment: In Powershell, `$?` is an example of an "automatic variable."  It helped me to know the nomenclature.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It returns `true` if the last command was successful, else `false`.

However, there are a number of caveats and non-obvious behaviour (e.g. what exactly is meant by "success"). I strongly recommend reading [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20190425110754/https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powershell-error-handling-and-why-you-should-care/) for a fuller treatment.

For example, consider calling Get-ChildItem.

```
PS> Get-ChildItem 

PS> $? 
    True
```

$? will return `True` as the call to Get-ChildItem succeeded.

However, if you call Get-ChildItem on a directory which does not exist it will return an error.

```
PS> Get-ChildItem \Some\Directory\Which\Does\Not\Exist
    Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\Some\Directory\Which\Does\Not\Exist' because it does not exist.

PS> $?
    False
```

$? will return `False` here, as the previous command was not successful.

Comment: @MattHickford A command is something you execute using Powershell. It can be a cmdlet or an executable for example. See the example I've added.

Comment: What does 'successful' mean? Do you think it means 'if and only if $LastExitCode is 0'?

Comment: I've found a counter-example where $? is False but $LastExitCode is 0. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666101/powershell-lastexitcode-0-but-false-redirecting-stderr-to-stdout-gives-nat

Comment: The article link in the answer is dead.

Comment: @RobbVandaveer Thanks - I've linked to archive.org now.

Answer (score 7):

`$?` will contain `$false` if the last command resulted in an error.  It will contain `$true` if it did not.  In the **PowerShell v1** days, this was a common way to do error handling.  For example, in a script, if you wanted to check for the existence of a file and then print a custom message if it did not, you could do:

```
Get-Item -Path john -ErrorAction silentlycontinue;
if( -not $?)
{
    'could not find file.';
     exit
 }`
```

Comment: What do people do now instead?

Comment: @mikemaccana, in the same boat here.... I would think try/catch statements.

Comment: try/catch is available in PS, but exceptions are only 'caught' when there is a terminating error. Often, a cmdlet won't terminate the execution but will continue on. In these cases, $? is you're alternative.

Answer (score 3):

You can also access last commands exit code using `$LastExitCode` parameter.

```
# run some command
# ...
if ((! $?) -and $ErrorAction -eq "Stop") { exit $LastExitCode }
```

Comment: Did you mean $ErrorActionPreference?

Comment: $? returns true if the last command was successful, else false.
Detailed info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10634171/1056566

Comment: I know. That's not what I asked :)

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered in Windows Server 2019, $? can be set false when Standard Error has been generated. In my example docker-compose logs warnings via Standard Error, so although exiting with 0, $? indicates failure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just saved me from an exploding artery in my head. I'm running a powershell script in a Jenkins build that executes Selenium tests. A Chrome browser and web driver upgrade just started logging an error, but the test passed. The `$?` variable was `$False` but `$LastExitCode` was zero. This build has been failing for a while now, and this answer finally pinpointed the failure. Basically don't trust `$?`. Use `$LastExitCode` instead.

Comment: In my case it's the opposite. ExitCode is 0 but the command failed, so I have to check `$?`. Seems like a common issue (when using PS with AWS: https://github.com/aws/amazon-ssm-agent/issues/69)

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT!!!**
Pleas be aware of the answer from Jules Clements.
$? can return false even $LastExitCode returns 0.

Even requesting $? causes that its content will change.

**Example:**
Some command causes that $? is false.
write $? => will return "false" for the first time
write $? => will return "true" for the second time

Comment: Some further refinement to my approach in later versions of windows (> 2016), when calling programs rather than commandlets, I execute them within a CMD subshell, e.g.

`cmd /c docker-compose up -d target 2>&1`

then I test $LASTEXITCODE