# PowerShell equivalent of cmd "IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0"

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Looking for the PowerShell equivalent of this cmd error-check:

`IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0`

Here is the PowerShell code I am trying to write:

```
Write-Information "Installing .NET 3 from DVD:"
$NetFX3_Source = "D:\Sources\SxS"
dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:$NetFX3_Source /NoRestart
IF (****TheCommandYouTellMe****) {
Write-Information "DVD not found, installing from online sources, the Win default method"
DISM.EXE /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:NetFx3~~~~
Add-WindowsCapability –Online -Name NetFx3~~~~
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is \`$?\` in Powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634115/what-is-in-powershell)

Comment: `$?` for internal commands, `$LASTEXITCODE` for external

Comment: I am looking for how to check if ANY error & do this if error exists. I appreciate you telling me which variable to check, but HOW do I check it?

Comment: Good distinction @MathiasR.Jessen, retracting close vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `dism.exe` is an external program, you'd want to check the `$LASTEXITCODE` automatic variable:

```
dism /online /andsoon
if($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
{
    # Add your capability
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Mathias R. Jessen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37792457/11159476) acually answers the specific question but not the entirety of `PowerShell equivalent of cmd "IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0"` (it did not do the job for me since I want to check `dir` error that is an internal program and `$LASTEXITCODE` is only for external programs as I understood), a more generic test would be:

```
dism ...
if ($? -ne $true) {
    # Add your capability
}
```

Or:

```
dism ...
if ($? -eq $false) {
    # Add your capability
}
```

But while it is more generic, it is less flexible since I assume programs setting `$LASTEXITCODE` can return different code depending on what happened during execution then react differently depending on situation, whereas with `$?` we have only success (`$true`) or fail (`$false`), for instance:

```
if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)
{
    echo Success
}
elseif ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 1)
{
    # Treat whatever last exit code = 1 means
}
elseif ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 2)
{
    # Treat whatever last exit code = 2 means
}
...
```